# Can I use "metamorphose" this way?

Tags: word-usage, sentence-construction

My own example:

> "I will get me metamorphosed in this tough life and eventually make me a man of quick parts" 
>  "a lot of entomologist think metamorphosing these moth would take so long time"

Comment: While it's not incorrect to use "metamorphose" as a verb, it's definitely far more frequently used as a noun: "entomologists think this moth's metamorphosis would take a long time". In the moth example especially, I read the verb form as indicating that the entomologists actually *controlled and directed* the moth's changes, rather than simply observing them.

Comment: Actually,i dissent from your opinion..You would find it correct as a verb if you check the dictionary..this word also can be used as a verb.but it is just not that common...or am i wrong still?

Comment: `It's not incorrect to use "metamorphose" as a verb` means the same as `You would find it correct as a verb if you check the dictionary`. Likewise, `it's definitely far more frequently used as a noun` means the same as `can be used as a verb.but it is just not that common`. So there is no dissent; we are in agreement.

Answer (score 1):

I agree with Dan Henderson in his [comment](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/67469/can-i-use-metamorphose-this-way#comment129373_67469). So, I'll post this as a (community wiki) answer:

> While it's not incorrect to use "metamorphose" as a verb, it's definitely far more frequently used as a noun: "entomologists think this moth's metamorphosis would take a long time". In the moth example especially, I read the verb form as indicating that the entomologists actually *controlled and directed* the moth's changes, rather than simply observing them.

(In other words, we use *metamorphose* much less often than its noun: *metamorphosis*.)

Also, as he noted in [another comment](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/67469/can-i-use-metamorphose-this-way#comment129426_67469):

> *It's not incorrect to use "metamorphose" as a verb*
>   (= You would find it correct as a verb if you check the dictionary.)
>
> *[I]t's definitely far more frequently used as a noun*
>   (= it can be used as a verb, but it is just not that common.)

And that answers your question.

Comment: *Metamorphose* is a valid verb but you should consider it to have a strong scientific or academic connotation.  Out of scientific contexts or specifically talking about butterflies or bugs it will sound jarring.  *I will get me metamorphosed* in particular sounds extremely jarring unless you have a strong context in the listener's/reader's mind where it can be connected to bugs or butterflies, and even then, it will still sound weird.

Answer (score 0):

You can use 'metamorphosing' as a verb in both the sentences, so yes, you can use it.

However, the sentences can be written in a better way.

IMO -

> I'll metamorphose myself in this.... 
>  A lot of entomologists think *that* metamorphosing these mothS ....